# Disable dates in angular

Tags: angular, date, disable

I'm working with calendar in angular with start and end dates.
I want to disable the previous dates , while selecting a start date and an end date.

```
<input type = "date"/>
```

Please help me achieve this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max` and `min` property of the `input` tag

Eg: `<input type="date" min="2020-01-01" max="2020-03-31">`

the format for `min` and `max` is in case of `date input` is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Thank you for the response. But my date format is dd/mm/yyyy sir.

Comment: I will try to share a working stackblitz. Please help me sir.

Comment: Sure, please share!

Comment: @ria , you can easily get the desired format of date by JavaScript. If you want extended features you can have a look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s638ox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css
This is my stackblitz.
with min and max. We are giving dates by default.
I'm working with angular and i want today's date to be taken as minimum date automatically iwhtout changing it manually everyday.
How can we do that sir.

Comment: In your code you can simply format the date using Angular's date pipe and pass it to date input. 

Eg: `<input type="date" min="{{todaysdate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" />`



You can just change the date formatting to  `yyyy-MM-dd` and that should fulfill your requirement.

I hope that helps, if so, I would appreciate an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help, I use DatePipe from angular/common

in component

```
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";

export class AppComponent {
   now: any;

   ngOnInit() {
     const datePipe = new DatePipe('en-Us');
     this.now = datePipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
   }
}
```

in html

```
<input type="date" [min]="now" required="required" />
```